# Refresh token is never used due multiple ADTokenCacheStoreItems - ADALiOS

Tags: ios, oauth-2.0, adal, microsoft-graph-api

Upon a successful login to the Microsoft Graph API service, 2 `ADTokenCacheStoreItems` are created. One of them contains the accessToken (refreshToken is nil) and the other one contains the refreshToken (accessToken is nil).

[image]

Having 2 cached items is fine but it is causing the refresh token logic to fail. The `[attemptToUseCacheItem:]` method uses the `ADTokenCacheStoreItem` that contains the accessToken. If the accessToken is expired, it checks the refresh token. In this item, the refresh token is nil so the whole process fails with the **'Attempting to use an item without refresh token'** error. The second item (with the refresh token) is actually never accessed.

As a result, the access token is never refreshed. What seems to be the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ADALiOS is working well, I can't reproduce the issue. The issue is resolved, the details are in the thread: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-objc/issues/598#issuecomment-211636229

Copying over Ryan's response here just in case the link goes down:

> The access token is stored separately from the Multi Resource Refresh
>   token in the cache for ADALiOS. If you call acquireTokenSilent it will
>   successfully refresh an AT from the MRRT.
>
> The line "The second item (with the refresh token) is actually never
>   accessed." is false. Look at -attemptToUseCacheItem: in
>   ADAuthenticationContext (1.2.x) or ADAuthenticationRequest (2.1) you
>   can see where ADAL looks for the MRRT and tries it. Look for the
>   "//Try multi-resource refresh token if not currently trying it"
>   comment if you're having a hard time finding it.
>
> There is a considerable amount of unit testing around this very
>   scenario and you try try it manually in the test app as well. The only
>   way you see the behavior you claim is if you're not using the proper
>   acquireToken entry points.